# How to make the WP query search for the "s" arg in other places too

Tags: wp-query, search

By default, the WP query searches for the "s" arg in the post title, content and excerpt.

How can I extend this and make it search in other places as well, such as author display name?

Example: When searching for "Test", show posts that contain "Test" in the title/content/excerpt OR in the author display name.

**Edit**: I solved the requirement using the [WP Extended Search](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-extended-search/) plugin (Extended Search/Author Setting/Search in Author display name). However, I am going to leave the question open, for a possible code solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search for posts IN OR title OR content OR author?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173193/how-to-search-for-posts-in-or-title-or-content-or-author)

Comment: @birgire I found that thread while researching but the code does not look right to me.